# ORA-22905 in parameterized query

Tags: parameter-passing, oracle9i

I have a function, that splits a CSV-list into a table of numbers.:

`create or replace function SYC_SplitIds
(IDList in varchar2)
return SYC_IDNRTABLE pipelined ...`

where SYC_IDNRTABLE is declared as:

`SYC_IDNRTable as table of spectrum.SYC_IDNR;`

and SYC_IDNR is:

`type SYC_IDNr as object(IDNr Integer)`

The function itself works fine. At least a query like this works OK:

`INSERT INTO TEST_TEMP_IDS
    SELECT IDNr AS ID 
    FROM Table(SYC_SplitIDs ('1234,5678'));`

However if I try the same query with a parameter instead of a fixed string:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TEMP_IDS
 SELECT IDNr AS ID 
 FROM Table(SYC_SplitIDs (:IDLIST));
```

where IDLIST is declared as VARCHAR2(32767) and initialized with the same '1234,5678' string as before, I get an, at least for me, strange ORA-22905 error: “cannot access rows from a non nested table item”

I found that I can avoid this error using:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TEMP_IDS SELECT IDNr AS ID 
  FROM Table(SYC_SplitIDs (CAST(:IDLIST AS VARCHAR(4000)));
```

but now I'm limitit to max 4000 bytes which is not enough... How to get the full 32767 byte range back?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TEMP_IDS SELECT IDNr AS ID FROM Table(SYC_SplitIDs (CAST(:IDLIST AS VARCHAR(4000)));
```

but now I've limit it to max 4000 bytes which is not enough... How to get the full 32767 byte range back?

Maybe you can try using `"(CAST(:IDLIST AS VARCHAR(MAX)));"`

this might solve the purpose.